# Apache Camel: set body with regex pattern in Spring DCL

Tags: regex, apache-camel, transform

I try to set String body, having cut from it the piece, with the the regular expression, as follows:

```
<setBody>
  <simple>${body} regex '?(:.xml xsi:type="xsd:string">(.*[\s\S]*?)..xml>)'</simple>
</setBody>
```

it is compiled normally but started with an error:

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Illegal processing instruction target ("xml"); xml (case insensitive) is reserved by the specs.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [6,7]
```

also I rty to do this with

```
<transform> ... </transform>
```

and the same error appears while running.

Please provide me the simple way to transform the body String in spring DSL by cutting it.

I want to cut xml data from soap plain request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:SMSServiceControllerwsdl">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:sendMessages soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <xml xsi:type="xsd:string">
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <Structure>
                <Array name="messageArray">
                    <Structure>
                        <Value name="id">
                            <Type>String</Type>
                            <Data>ИД СООБЩЕНИЯ 1</Data>
                        </Value>
                        <Value name="phone">
                            <Type>String</Type>
                            <Data>ТЕЛЕФОН 1</Data>
                        </Value>
                        <Value name="text">
                            <Type>String</Type>
                            <Data>ТЕКСТ 1</Data>
                        </Value>
                    </Structure>
                    <Structure>
                        <Value name="id">
                            <Type>String</Type>
                            <Data>ИД СООБЩЕНИЯ 2</Data>
                        </Value>
                        <Value name="phone">
                            <Type>String</Type>
                            <Data>ТЕЛЕФОН 2</Data>
                        </Value>
                        <Value name="text">
                            <Type>String</Type>
                            <Data>ТЕКСТ 2</Data>
                        </Value>
                    </Structure>
                </Array>
            </Structure>         
         </xml>
         <systemName xsi:type="xsd:string">awis</systemName>
      </urn:sendMessages>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: This is not valid XML: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` is only allowed as a prologue at the beginning of a file.

Comment: Yes, you are right.
The solution for me is cutting the xml prolog
`<transform>      <simple>${body.replaceAll("&lt;\?xml.+?\?&gt;", "")}</simple>
</transform>`
And then use xpath or xslt transformation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [splitter](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) with an XPath expression such as:

```
<split>
    <xpath>//Structure/Array/Structure</xpath>
    <log message="split: ${body}"/>
</split>
```